# General equation for the number of combinations that connect upper part and lower part of grid

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms

Given a square grid with either open or closed cells where open allows a path to be created across the cell. What would be the general equation that describes how many combinations create a path from the top of the grid to the bottom of the grid given the dimensions of the grid and the number of open cells.

```
Here is an example of a 2 by 2 grid with 2 open cells:
1 represents open 
0 represents closed

Path=True
1 0
1 0

Path=False
1 0
0 1

Path=False
0 1
1 0

Path=True
0 1
0 1

Path=False
1 1
0 0

Path=False
0 0
1 1

So in this example the result would be 2 as only 2 out of the six possible combinations allow a path from top to bottom.
```

Comment: could someone provide some of this problem values? I'm just curious if that's a OEIS sequence

Comment: Ive tried making a program to calculate but its so slow and I'm not even sure if I've made mistakes on the code, ill post the results bellow anyway. Side length of the grid is "s" and open cells is "n". When S=2, n=2: 2, when n=3: 4. When S=3, n=3:3, when n=4:22, when n=5:59, when n=6:67, when n=7:36, when n=8:9. I've got more results if you want, but as I said, i have a feeling the program is faulty.